# Define array of own class in constructor with parameter in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, constructor, runtime

How to create an array of an own class in a constructor of another class with a size and a parameter that is given during runtime?

```
class Row {
  ...
  Row(int n) { ... }
  ...
}
```

I want to use it in:

```
class Foo {
  Row *row; // pointer to array containing rows

  Foo(int n, int y) {
    row = new Row[y](n);
  }
}
```

Thats not working and didnt find a solution for that.
I also read about Vector and reserve but how can he know the size of Row?

Comment: `std::vector<Row> row;` would be the right tool for that. It can be initialized in the constructor member initializer list as `row(y,n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also read about Vector and reserve

When you say "Vector", you probably mean `std::vector`.

`reserve` is a member function of `std::vector`, but it has nothing to do with your problem (if I understand it correctly), as it just concerns the vector's internal memory management.

```
class Foo {
  std::vector<Row> rows;

  Foo(int n, int y) : rows(y, n) {} // no call to `reserve` necessary

  // ...
};
```

> but how can he know the size of Row?

You probably mean how a `std::vector` seems to be able to initialise a dynamic array of `Row` objects passing each one a constructor argument, while your own code's attempt fails at doing so.

The answer is that `std::vector` (or rather, `std::allocator`, which is the default allocator used in the `std::vector` template) does *not* use `new[]`. It uses a C++ feature called [placement new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new).

Simply speaking, this allows the vector to separate memory allocation and constructor calls. It is a low-level memory-management technique, highly dangerous in the wrong hands.

But it cannot hurt to be aware of its existence, even as a beginner, because it underlines the fact that `new[]` and `delete[]` are really misfeatures of C++. Just don't use them. **Use standard container classes like `std::vector`.** And even if you should ever, one far-away day in some years from now, have to write your own very low-level container class, placement new will be a better choice.

Comment: Hi if I understand correctly, vector is a kind of list, so i dont have constant(instant) access to the elements?

Comment: @Sneedlewoods: No. You are confusing `std::vector` with `std::list`. Element access for a vector runs in constant time, i.e. O(1).

Comment: I am still confused about Foo(int n, int y) : rows(y, n) {} - I want to do something like for (int i = 1; i <= y; i++) { row.insert(new Row(n) } where row is now std::vector<Row> row;

Comment: @Sneedlewoods: And what exactly is wrong with `Foo(int n, int y) : rows(y, n) {}`?

Comment: rows is a vector, i dont understand what this rows(y, n) does, how can the vector know what to do with it.